# using wget shell exec with args

Tags: php, linux, wget, shell-exec

i have a weird problem in my script,
i'm trying to use wget to download file... after the first GET var it's just igonre the rest.

my code:

```
$data = shell_exec("wget http://www.domain.com/file.php?id=51B82153C123C6BE&key=09cfa30c2261cf5a -o progress.log & echo $! > errors.log");
```

what i mean is why it does't use the key GET and only the first GET for the id?

Comment: did you try quoting the url part of the command?